# Hadoop Automation with Automic (UC4)

Tags: linux, hadoop, application-server, uc4, automic

We have HADOOP servers(Linux dist.) and Application server(SQL). We will implement Automic Engine in order to automated our hadoop env.

What is the best way to implementation?

Where do we locate agents on application server or hadoop servers?

Answer (score 0):

There are PDF files located on the installation media which explain the installation of the RA agent for Hadoop.  You will find them in the directory named Rapid.Automation/RA.Hadoop.

As for your SQL agent, you will find the installation files in the directory named Automation.Platform/Agents/sql.  There you will find sub-directories for unix and windows.  If it is a Windows server, simply run the setup.exe file in the windows sub-directory.  If it is a Unix server, you will need to gunzip the .gz file, then extract the tar file to a directory of your choice (usually something like /opt/automic/VERSION/agents/sql).

After installing the sql agent, you will need to follow the installation procedure in the Administration Guide/Installation in the Automic documentation in order to modify the ini file for the SQL agent.  The setup of this ini file is similar to that of the other types of agents.